# Using Commands in Nano

Tags: linux, date, nano

I want to display the date as a user would log onto a system in CLI. I was editing the .bashrc file to say to the CLI the username, hostname, and date. How would you use the date command in nano? I tried putting it in regularly and it would just print out 'date', not the actual date. How would i run the command date in nano?

Comment: Something like: `echo $(date)` would probably do what you want to do. Like: `echo $USER $HOSTNAME $(date)`.Also, Nano is just the text editor your are using. You could edit your `.bashrc` in windows notepad, but you wouldn't say "How would i run the command `date` in Notepad". "How can I echo the results of the command `date` in my .bashrc file" would be a lot less confusing.

Comment: oh ok. Thanks. Yeah i was editing the .bashrc to say that to me when i logged in.